# How to change background overlay in Jetpack compose Dialog?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Dialog/AlertDialog created using Compose. Now I have a problem where I need to be able to make changes to the overlay in the transparent dialog.

How can I replace it?

Comment: Hi, If possible could you share design code snippet to understand how you designed it.

Comment: Hi @AndroidTeam , i made like this:

`Dialogue(
onDismissRequest = { }
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(dialogWidth)
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            color = black
        ) {
}
}`